# save entity with null reference

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I would like to know if for example I have entity like customer and customer addresss and address is a reference in 
in customer what will happen if I dont find match with the entities keys some instance of customer will need to be saved with address null
what will happen in the commit ,i will get dump?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what technique are you using and what DB schema have you defined.
Typically object graph is represented in relational DB as a number of tables with foreign keys that represent references between objects. If the field (the FK) is nullable, so you can save customer without address. Otherwise constraint violation exception will be thrown.

If you need more information please post some of your code and explain what is the persistence technology that you are using.

Comment: I use the entitymanager to persist all the objects and than i do entitymanager.commit at the end for all the objects and IM not sure how behavior regard null referance,from my POV if the FG is null I will get dump but for any other referance 1:1 or 1:n I will not get dump if for some key object there is no referance ,pls correct me if im wrong...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Imo,  if you db allows nulls in the address column (and no FK constraints exists), it will save nulls. Else, it should fail.